# Logstash jdbc plugin: how use a date filter for a column?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-jdbc

In my MS SQL table, i have a column with date stored as string on format "dd-mm-yyyy 00:00:00.000"
for example : 1999-10-06 00:00:00.000 or 2000-04-27 00:00:00.000

During my import, i want to convert this column's values into date type.

I saw a feature called filter which could do this type of transformation.
I found examples but only for parsing logs full text lines brought by Beats with sort of regex.

How to use this feature  for a sql column?
For example, how  adapt this conf file for making it working for real?

```
 input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:localhost;"
          jdbc_user => "user"
          jdbc_password => "pass"
       jdbc_driver_library => "C:\Program Files (x86)\jdbc\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\sqljdbc42.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        statement => "SELECT  * FROM SOLD"
    }
}

filter
{
     date {
         match => [ "DATE_COLUMN", "YYYY-MM-dd 00:00:00.000" ]
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch { 
       hosts => "localhost:9200"
       index => "indexname"
       document_type => "typename"

    }
}
```

For the moment this conf does not work and create this ES text field:

```
 "date_column": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
          }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so answere was to make this filter in writing the name of column in  **lowercase**:

```
filter
{
     date {
         match => [ "date_column", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
    }
}
```

And to make an elasticsearch  mapping column for this date format:

```
PUT /index
{
     "mappings": {
      "type": {
        "properties": {
         "date_column": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a field in your database called myDateField, you should get a field with the same name after using the JDBC input{}.  You can then ask logstash to process ("filter") and output this data.

There are over 50 filters included with logstash (see [the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/filter-plugins.html)).

To make your field into a date, use the date{} filter.  Note that this filter is usually used to set logstash's "@timestamp" field, but you can put the date into a different field (or even overwrite the same field) if you want.

Comment: thank you for your answere  but I have already  noticed filters are what i need to use . i fail for making it work in my case and i would like to see an example for my case where i want to override a field. It is maybe obvious but my tries are unsuccessful and i don't find a full example

Comment: Posting what you've tried, the input you've provided, the result you received, and the result you wanted, would help people diagnose the issue.